# Buffered Reader Not Working

Tags: android

I am a beginer android developer.I am trying this code. But it always goes into exception. But if i remove BufferedReader then it works fine.

package com.toha.buffercheck;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.net.URL;

import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.os.Bundle;  

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

EditText ets , etc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            URL url = null;


            url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            tv.setText("Working Till Now");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            tv.setText("Stopped Working");
        }
    }
```

And The LogCat keeps Saying "The application may be too much of work on its main thread"

PS: it works fine on the emulator version 2.3.3
but does not on the emulator version 4.2.2

Comment: It is not working on version 4.2.2, because since android version 2.3.3 you cannot perform network work on the main thread. Just use AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

**Error:"The application may be too much of work on its main thread"**

Do not block the UI thread
Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

**Worker threads**

Because of the single thread model described above, it's vital to the responsiveness of your application's UI that you do not block the UI thread. If you have operations to perform that are not instantaneous, you should make sure to do them in separate threads ("background" or "worker" threads).

AsyncTask allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.

**Don't load data in main thread. Use other thread for http request, for example:**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       try {
          URL url = null;

          url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
       } catch(Exception e) {
           Log.i("Error on load data:", "" + e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}).start();
```

Or use AsyncTask for load data:[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: Thank You all, I used AsyncTask to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is common, you are trying to perform some long running operation on the main thread of your application.

What that means, is that the main thread is in charge of updating the UI, to enforce a smooth experience, if android detects you are doing some long running operation that is going to be blocking, it will force shutdown the app, to let you know that this is bad.

There are many alternative solution, such as AsynTask, or IntentService.

IntentService is a service that runs when you sent a intent to it:

```
public class NetworkHandler extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         //Do your request here
    }
}
```

To activate the IntentService, simply do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NetworkHandler.class);
startService(intent);
```